# Date range comparison off-by-one

Tags: oracle, date, comparison

There is a table in Oracle 19c with a `DATE abc` column. A row with value '2000-01-01' does not get picked up with query

```sql
select abc from t where abc <= DATE '2000-01-01'
```

The row does surface if I modify the query as

```sql
select abc from t where abc < DATE '2000-01-01' + interval '1' day
```

The displayed value (in DBeaver, VSCode + Oracle Dev Tools, Oracle SQL Developer) is always '2000-01-01'.

Comment: The modified query is correct as it does take account of date/time including a time part. E.g. it will also return a date like `2000-01-01 23:59:59` but not `2000-01-02 00:00:00`. It is not an off-by-one issue. It is a time-part issue.

Answer (score 2):

### Issue

Oracle stores also time portion of inserted/copied data and while it doesn't always show, it affects queries regardless of output data.

You can notice it with query:

```sql
select to_char(abc, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:MI:ss') from t 
where trunc(abc) <= date '2000-01-01'
```

### Mitigation

- **use** the comparable date (you're searching for) as variable and add `+ interval '1' day` to it. Notice to adjust your comparison limits, use `<` instead of `<=` to not accidentally find items from next day with `00:00:00` time.
- **don't use** `trunc(abc)` or `to_char(abc ..)`, it will likely wreck the index performance`
- add `ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';` to your sql editor startup script.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type that consists of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 bytes and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular (human-readable) format.

> The displayed value (in DBeaver, VSCode + Oracle Dev Tools, Oracle SQL Developer) is always '2000-01-01'.

What you are seeing is the client application receiving the binary `DATE` value and trying to be helpful and **displaying** the binary value as a string; however, the client application's default format is `YYYY-MM-DD` and it is not showing the time component of the date. This does not mean that the time component does not exist, it only means that it is not displayed.

What you need to do is to go into the preferences and change how your client application formats dates.

In SQL Developer, you can use:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Which will set the format for your current session. Or you can go into  `Tool > Settings > Database > NLS` and in set the "Date Format" field to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` which will set the preference for the current session and any future session that you create from that client.

You can do something similar and change the settings in most (all) client applications.

---

> ```
> select abc from t where abc <= DATE '2000-01-01'
> ```

Is the equivalent of:

> ```
> select abc from t where abc <= TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
> ```

It will not match rows where `abc` is between `2000-01-01 00:00:01` and `2000-01-01 23:59:59` but the client application is not displaying the time component so you cannot see that the rows have a non-midnight time component and should not be matched.

If you do:

> ```sql
> select abc from t where abc < DATE '2000-01-01' + interval '1' day
> ```

Then it will match those rows because it will match the entire 24-hour period for the day.